# Alterar função jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou tendo um problema com um código jquery, eu encontrei um código quase perfeito para minha utilização, porém, tem um função que não me serve e eu não consigo desabilita-la.

Essa função é a de quando clico em alguma coluna do thead(as que tem duas setinhas), a ordem da minha tabela muda de ascendente para decrescente, porem para mim, só está atrapalhando. Ao invés de carregar o script responsável por essas funções como arquivo externo, eu salvei ele e carrego internamente para poder altera-lo, mas me falta conhecimento suficiente pra conseguir encontrar essa função no meio do código e apaga-la sem prejudicar o restante do código. Então se alguém puder me dar alguma ajuda, eu agradeço muito.

Segue o código abaixo.

O arquivo externo referente as funções é: `cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <center> <h1>Log das Integrações</h1> </center>
        <div class="table-responsive" >
            <table id="minhaTabela" class="display table" width="100%">
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ID</th>  
            <th>Nome</th>  
            <th>Valor</th>  
            <th>Erro</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>200</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Ingrid</td>  
            <td>800</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>006</td>  
            <td>Letícia</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  

           <tr>  
            <td>007</td>  
            <td>Ronaldo</td>  
            <td>800</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>008</td>  
            <td>Mike</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>009</td>  
            <td>Andrew</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  

            <tr>  
            <td>010</td>  
            <td>Stephen</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>011</td>  
            <td>Sara</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>012</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
</table>
        </div>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#minhaTabela').dataTable();
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apagar a parte do código que permite re-ordenar a tabela é arriscado, para não dizer impossível pois esse código está inserido dentro da biblioteca que é o plugin DataTable. Porém o sensato é configurar o plugin para não ordenar a tabela. E isso é simples.

Esse método `.dataTable()` que inicia a tabela aceita um [objeto de configuração](https://datatables.net/reference/option/#DataTables_Table_0). Assim passa `ordering:  false` e a opção fica desabilitada.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#minhaTabela').dataTable({ordering:  false});
});
```

Exemplo a funcionar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <center> <h1>Log das Integrações</h1> </center>
        <div class="table-responsive" >
            <table id="minhaTabela" class="display table" width="100%">
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ID</th>  
            <th>Nome</th>  
            <th>Valor</th>  
            <th>Erro</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>200</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Ingrid</td>  
            <td>800</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>006</td>  
            <td>Letícia</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          
           <tr>  
            <td>007</td>  
            <td>Ronaldo</td>  
            <td>800</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>008</td>  
            <td>Mike</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>009</td>  
            <td>Andrew</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          
            <tr>  
            <td>010</td>  
            <td>Stephen</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>011</td>  
            <td>Sara</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>012</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
</table>
        </div>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#minhaTabela').dataTable({ordering:  false});
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Respondemos no mesmo minuto com a mesma coisa :) `+1`

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a [documentação](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering) do `dataTable`, basta adicionar:

`"ordering": false` no construtor do dataTable.

Ficando assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <center> <h1>Log das Integrações</h1> </center>
        <div class="table-responsive" >
            <table id="minhaTabela" class="display table" width="100%">
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ID</th>  
            <th>Nome</th>  
            <th>Valor</th>  
            <th>Erro</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>200</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Ingrid</td>  
            <td>800</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>006</td>  
            <td>Letícia</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          
           <tr>  
            <td>007</td>  
            <td>Ronaldo</td>  
            <td>800</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>008</td>  
            <td>Mike</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>009</td>  
            <td>Andrew</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Sim</td>  
          </tr>  
          
            <tr>  
            <td>010</td>  
            <td>Stephen</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>011</td>  
            <td>Sara</td>  
            <td>400</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>012</td>  
            <td>Davi</td>  
            <td>300</td>  
            <td>Não</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
</table>
        </div>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#minhaTabela').dataTable({
         "ordering": false
    });
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Respondemos no mesmo minuto com a mesma coisa :) `+1`